# How to merge iterator parser

Tags: scala, iterator

I have an `Iterator[(A1,B1)]` and two functions

- `fA: (Iterator[A1]) => Iterator[A2]` and
- `fB: (Iterator[B1]) => Iterator[B2]`.

Is it possible to make a `fAB: (Iterator[(A1,B1)]) => Iterator[(A2,B2)]` without converting Iterators to Seq?

#### Edit

Both answers below are good. I selected [@Aivean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36635052/1206998) because the code is simpler and it uses specialized scala data structure (Stream).

The only drawback is the stackoverfow limitation but it shouldn't be a problem for most use cases. If your iterator can be very (very) long, then [@Alexey's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36624367/1206998) should be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to much simpler implementation:

```
def iterUnzip[A1, B1, A2, B2](it: Iterator[(A1, B1)],
                           fA: (Iterator[A1]) => Iterator[A2],
                           fB: (Iterator[B1]) => Iterator[B2]) =
  it.toStream match {
    case s => fA(s.map(_._1).toIterator).zip(fB(s.map(_._2).toIterator))
  }
```

The idea is to convert iterator to stream. `Stream` in Scala is lazy but also provides [memoization](http://blog.dmitryleskov.com/programming/scala/stream-hygiene-i-avoiding-memory-leaks/). This effectively provides the same buffering mechanism, as in @AlexeyRomanov's solution, but more concise. The only drawback is that `Stream` stores memoized elements on stack as opposed to the explicit Queue, thus if `fA` and `fB` produce elements on uneven rate, you may get StackOverflow exception.

Test that evaluation is lazy indeed:

```
val iter = Stream.from(0).map(x => (x, x + 1))
  .map(x => {println("fetched: " + x); x}).take(5).toIterator

iterUnzip(
  iter,
  (_:Iterator[Int]).flatMap(x => List(x, x)),
  (_:Iterator[Int]).map(_ + 1)
).toList
```

Result:

```
fetched: (0,1)
iter: Iterator[(Int, Int)] = non-empty iterator

fetched: (1,2)
fetched: (2,3)
fetched: (3,4)
fetched: (4,5)
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,2), (0,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,6))
```

I also tried reasonably hard to get StackOverflow exception by producing uneven iterators, but failed.

```
val iter = Stream.from(0).map(x => (x, x + 1)).take(10000000).toIterator
iterUnzip(
    iter,
    (_:Iterator[Int]).flatMap(x => List.fill(1000000)(x)),
    (_:Iterator[Int]).map(_ + 1)
  ).size
```

Works fine on `-Xss5m` and produces:

```
res10: Int = 10000000
```

So, overall this is reasonably good and concise solution, unless you have some extreme usecases.

Comment: A very nice solution. One potential drawback is that it's slightly less lazy: if `fA` and `fB` never request any elements, my answer doesn't call `next()` on the original iterator, but `it.toStream` in yours does once.

Comment: Also, to my understanding, Stream will store all items read once, while @romanov solution dequeue items onces they have been read. Thus it can potentially not store all item. But on the other end, if we parse the full Iterator[A] before starting B, then all Bs are stored...

Comment: @Juh_ Initial elements of a `Stream` can be garbage-collected if you aren't holding on to a reference to them. I think this should happen here, but I am not completely sure.

Comment: @Juh_, @AlexeyRomanov is right, stream here works precisely like a Queue, releasing elements from the head once they are consumed. Only the "buffer" between two iterators is stored, if `fA` and `fB` generate elements with different ratio (as in my second test with `flatMap`). If `fA` and `fB` map elements one-to-one, then the whole thing becomes completely transient. I just checked once again, my function works fine where `Stream` assigned to value to prevent garbage collection fails.

Comment: I finally selected your answer as the code is simpler, it uses specialized scala data structure (Stream) and have the same good properties. The only drawback is the stackoverfow limitation but it souldn't be a problem for most use cases.

Answer (score 3):

No. Your hypothetical function has to call one of `fA` and `fB` first. Let's say it calls `fA` and it requests all the `A1`s before producing anything. Then you don't have any `B1`s remaining to pass to `fB`, unless you save them somewhere, potentially leaking memory. If that's acceptable, you can do:

```
def unzip[A, B](iter: Iterator[(A, B)]) = {
  var qA = Queue.empty[A]
  var qB = Queue.empty[B]

  val iterA = new Iterator[A] {
    override def hasNext = qA.nonEmpty || iter.hasNext

    override def next() = qA.dequeueOption match {
      case Some((a, qA1)) =>
        qA = qA1
        a
      case None =>
        val (a, b) = iter.next()
        qB = qB.enqueue(b)
        a
    }
  }

  // similar iterB

  (iterA, iterB)
}
```

and then

```
val (iterA, iterB) = unzip(iterator)
fA(iterAfA).zip(fB(iterB))
```

(Well, you can also write `iterator => fA(iterator.map(_._1)).zip(fB(iterator.map(_._2))`: it has the right type, but is probably not what you want. Namely, it will use only one field of each tuple produced by the original iterator, and drop the other.)